# how to make globalCompositeOperationSection affect only the save() and restore() context?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How can I make `globalCompositeOperation` affects only what is inside the save/restore() context?

For example, the red rectangle bellow is being affect by the "destination-atop" operator. What was expected to do is to fill the canvas with the red rectangle and see the black circle masked over it. And what is happening is that the red rectangle is also being masked.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let size1 = 350;
let size2 = 150;
let size3 = 154;

canvas.width  = size1;
canvas.height = size1; 
canvas.style.width  = size1+'px';
canvas.style.height = size1+'px';

//red rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, size1, size1);
ctx.fill();

// save the context state
ctx.save();

//black circle
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.ellipse(size2, size2, size2, size2, 0, 0, 6.28);
ctx.fill();

//mask
//shouldnt it mask only the shape before?
//why is it masking the red rectangle outside save/restore() context?
ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-atop";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.ellipse(size3, size3, size3, size3, 0, 0, 6.28);
ctx.fill();

ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" />
```

I know there is a way to create multiple canvas to combine them, or other techniques to mask, but my main question is about the `globalCompositeOperation` not respecting the save/restore() context...

Comment: Other similar questions but the answer is not satisfying:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972222/globalcompositeoperation-and-concentric-hollow-moving-shapes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621212/canvas-disappears-when-animating-source-in-globalcompositeoperation-mask

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836443/the-globalcompositeoperation-affected-to-all-layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save()` method saves all the current properties of your 2DContext in a stack of saved states. (`fillStyle`, `strokeStyle`, `font`, `lineWidth` etc.)
`restore()` will apply the last saved state in the stack, while removing it from the stack.

None of these methods have anything to do with what is drawn on the canvas, they just save some properties of a JS object (along with some inaccessible ones like clipping areas).

---

`globalCompositeOperation` will affect only the drawing operations that will happen after you did set it. They will have all to do with what is drawn on your canvas.

`save` and `restore` won't help you at all in what you wish to achieve. 
What you want, is to do your compositing on a separate canvas content, and for this, the easiest is to use a second canvas element:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let size1 = 350;
let size2 = 150;
let size3 = 154;

canvas.width  = size1;
canvas.height = size1; 
canvas.style.width  = size1+'px';
canvas.style.height = size1+'px';

const copycanvas = canvas.cloneNode();
const copyctx = copycanvas.getContext('2d');

//red rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, size1, size1);
ctx.fill();

//draw the mask on the off-screen canvas
//black circle
copyctx.fillStyle = "black";
copyctx.beginPath();
copyctx.ellipse(size2, size2, size2, size2, 0, 0, 6.28);
copyctx.fill();

// I guess you didn't really want a source-atop gCO here
copyctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-out";
copyctx.beginPath();
copyctx.ellipse(size3, size3, size3, size3, 0, 0, 6.28);
copyctx.fill();

ctx.drawImage(copycanvas, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" />
```

But you could also very well do this exact drawing all on the same canvas, by drawing in an other order:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let size1 = 350;
let size2 = 150;
let size3 = 154;

canvas.width  = size1;
canvas.height = size1; 
canvas.style.width  = size1+'px';
canvas.style.height = size1+'px';

//draw the mask first
//black circle
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.ellipse(size2, size2, size2, size2, 0, 0, 6.28);
ctx.fill();

// I guess you didn't really want a source-atop gCO here
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-out";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.ellipse(size3, size3, size3, size3, 0, 0, 6.28);
ctx.fill();

// finally, draw the background
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
//red rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, size1, size1);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" />
```